# Google OAuth returning invalid_grant Incorrect token type

Tags: java, angularjs, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-js-client

I get a valid code on the client side login of my application using angularJS Oauth Module GAuth.checkAuth(). and then GAuth.getToken().

The code is valid only for 1 hour and any API like GoogleDocs,Gmail accessed after 1 hour fails and needs relogin.

To overcome this I am trying to send the code to the server for getting AccessCode at Server so that I can send same with requests to GoogleDocs, Gmail etc

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest req =
 new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
  new NetHttpTransport(),
  JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
  "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
  // "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "901142925530-21ia7dqnsdsdsndnsnnnfdc9cm2u07.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "6NSvw0efghyuuG8YGOBWPln79n",
  authCode,
  "http://localhost:8080");
req.setGrantType("authorization_code");
//req.put("refresh_token", authCode);
//req.put("access_type", "offline");
GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse =
 req.execute();

tokenResponse.getAccessToken()
```

Where authCode is the code I received in GAuth Token

But the call is failing and in response I get

```
400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant",
  "error_description" : "Incorrect token type."
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you use the refresh token on the client side?

Comment: I was reading API and it said refresh token doesn't work at client side.So didn't spent much time exploring it. Is it feasible to use it at client side? Can you please let me know the steps?

Answer (score 0):

When the user first authenticates your application you are given an authorization code.   You then need to take this authorization code and exchange it for an access token and a refresh token.   Once the authorization code has been used it can not be used again.

> grant_type=authorization_code

Denotes that you are asking Google to verifiy that your authorization code and give you a new access token and refresh token.

It sound to me like you are taking either the access token returned from that request and sending it to grant_type=authorization_code end point which is not going to work its the wrong type of code.  hens the error you are getting of

> 400 Bad Request { "error" : "invalid_grant", "error_description" : "**Incorrect token type**." }

You will need to take the refresh token you are given.  If there is one I am not sure that you can even get a refresh token from AngularJs.  You can get one using java though.

A refresh of an access token in pure rest will look like this

```
  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
  client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&refresh_token=1/ffYmfI0sjR54Ft9oupubLzrJhD1hZS5tWQcyAvNECCA&grant_type=refresh_token
```

Note the `&grant_type=refresh_token`. If you are using the Google api java client library it should handle all of that for you.   However your tagging is a little confusing its unclear if you are trying to do this in java or angularjs which I do not believe will allow you to use refresh tokens.  Again I am not an angular dev I could be wrong on that point.

**Anwser:**

You the code you are sending is not an authorization code.  Only an authorization code can be sent to grant_type=authorization_code.  Solution: Send an **authorization_code**

**Types of Google codes and tokens:**

There are three types of codes or tokens you should be aware of with Oauth2.

1. Authorization code.
2. Refresh token
3. Access token

When you request access of a user and they grant your application access you are given an `Authorization code`.   The Authorization code is short lived it probably less then 10 minutes and it can only be used once.

The Authorization code is used to get the initial access token and the refresh token from googles authentication server.   by using the `grant_type=authorization_code`

Access token are good for about an hour.   They are used to make calls to google APIs

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token={your access token}
```

You can use the access token as often as you want during that hour assuming you don't blow out some quota.

Refresh tokens are used to request a new access token from the Google authentication server when the access token you have current has expired or you just want a new one.   here the `grant_type=refresh_token` is used to request a new access token you are essentially telling google I am sending you a refresh token you know what to do.

**additional reading**

I have a coupe of tutorials that might help you out [Google 3 Legged OAuth2 Flow](http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/) and [Google Developer Console Oauth2 credentials](http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-oauth2/)

Also helpful when learning Oauth: [The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)

Comment: Thanks!  Sorry but my assumption was that when I login through JAPI/AngularJS I get authorization code and that I send to server for exchange. Can you please explain me the difference between access token  and authorization code  mentioned in your first 2 paragraphs. May be that will help me. So basically I am doing authentication on the client side using GAPI(And AngularJS) and trying to get access code on the server side for reuse. Since Ours is a web App,found it more feasible. Do you suggest to do the authentication on Server side?

Comment: I have a tutorial that explains oauth flow in raw HTTP calls.  http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/   You should be authenticating on the  server side not the client side I am not sure that Gapi is going to give you a refresh token that you can use.

Comment: Thanks again! But I am having this doubt. How do we do authentication on the server? It is integrated with the web browser and the request directly goes to the google server. Google wont allow us (or wont be wise even if it is doable) to store the user credentials on our server. Currently a new google window pops up and on authentication we get the access code in callback function.

Comment: yup and then you exchange it and get an access token which is only good for an hour.  Then you will have to ask the user to authenticate you again.    Try googleing refresh token and gapi I am not a javascript programmer so cant really help with that I found this though https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/help/faq#does-the-javascript-client-library-set-authentication--------cookies

Comment: Note: You need to either ask the user for access evey hour or figure out how to get a refresh token.  There is no work around those are your only two options.   What you are doing right now is not going to work you can only use the authorization code once and you cant use an access token to request a new access token.   You need to find the refresh token and refresh that.

Comment: req.setGrantType("refresh_token");
  req.put("refresh_token", authCode);
  //req.put("access_type", "offline");
      GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse = 
        req.execute();   tokenResponse.getRefreshToken();
 but it returns null

Comment: I think you need to read though the links I gave you and try to understand what you are doing instead of just dumping what ever grant type in you can think of.